# How can i check particular element in a multidimensional array php

Tags: php

I want to search **50075285** in this array.

```
$xyz=Array
(
    [typeA] => Array
        (
            [details_typeA] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50075285
                    [action_code] => PDF_ONLINE   
                )

        )

    [typeB] => Array
        (
            [details_typeB] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 50075287
                   [action_code] => offline
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Please write an appropriate question, not just a dump

Comment: If i am not wrong its a 3 dimensional array

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Unfortunately it's not really clear what you are asking. Are you wanting to do a value search on all elements or only specific keys? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, have a read of this https://steemit.com/php/@crell/php-use-associative-arrays-basically-never and then this https://steemit.com/php/@crell/php-never-type-hint-on-arrays for some food for thought on using associative arrays.

Comment: yes i want to do a value search  for example if i want to check  50075285 is present or not

Answer (score 0):

```
//this gives the exact value in a specific array
//in this case this is the value you want. 
$value = $xyz['typeA']['details_typeA']['id'];
```

OR

```
//this gives every id in the `details_typeX` array
foreach($xyz as $type){
    foreach($type as $details){
        $value = $details['id']
    }
}
```

[PHP Sandbox proof](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72347e15f75994cc1aab2dc549e9c5bb6c710fde)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

$key   array key the value should be associated with

$value value you are searching the array for

```
function arr_search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_object($array)){ $array = (array)$array; }

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, arr_search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your response. i am really happy it was really helped @Gobbin..

Comment: Thank You so much  @Mehdi..

Comment: @user10477731 your welcome, please mark as answered if this helped

Comment: $array1=  Array
(
    [0] => 50059685
    [1] => 50070059
    [2] => 50070086
    [3] => 50070087
    [4] => 50070084

    )


    array2=Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 50059685
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 50070059
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 50070084
    [6] => 4
   
    )